# Cannot add 'active' class by using addEventListner

Tags: javascript

```
<section>
    <nav id="s-nav" class="s-nav">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="nav-logo">
                    <img src="/images/Logo.svg" alt="Logo">
                </div>
        
                <ul class="nav-ul">
                    <li class="nav-li"><a href="">About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <ul><li><a href="#">Team</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            
        <div>
    <nav>
    </section> 

<script>
    const selector = document.querySelector('.nav-li');
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
    selector.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     dropdown.classList.add("active")
    })

</script>
```

I tried to add 'active' class to 'dropdown' class. But it doesn't work. Also, console.log(e.currentTarget.classList) is clearing out immediately.

Could you explain why?

Comment: Probably because you are clicking on the link (`<a>`), which will redirect you to the same page, causing the page to be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

The click triggers a navigation. So you need to prevent that. Add to the event handler:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change href="" to href='#" as below. If you keep an href empty it will reload current url.

```
    <li class="nav-li"><a href="#">About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your list element to this:

```
<li class="nav-li">
    <a href="#">About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you click a link inside your li element, so you're being redirected. Just add e.preventDefault();

```
const selector = document.querySelector('.nav-li');
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
selector.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  dropdown.classList.add("active")
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/co3xytLk/

Comment: Thanks so much...It's hard to understand preventDefault clearly but it works..

Comment: Check this out [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3ab59d4h/) If you add some styles to .nav-li, you can click on the part with grey background and your "Team" link will change background without using preventDefault. But before you were clicking not <li> element, but <a> element inside of <li>, so you were triggering default behavior of <a> - redirecting(following url). What e.preventDefault() does is, basically. prevent default actions from happening.